# dynamically change radio button height and font size in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to change height and font size of horizontal controlgroup radio buttons dynamically with jquery mobile 1.2.1

I can change size and font, but with some values the buttons are displayed toghether with the basic radio selector as in
http://picpaste.com/Capture-94sE5bZi.PNG

http://jsfiddle.net/mauix/VVpR9/15/

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="content">
<form>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="btnc1">
    <input name="rc" id="rca" value="on" checked="checked" type="radio">
    <label for="rca">#1</label>
    <input name="rc" id="rcb" value="off" type="radio">
    <label for="rcb">#2</label>
    <input name="rc" id="rcc" value="other" type="radio">
    <label for="rcc">#3</label>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>  
</body>

<script>
$('#rca').on('click', function(){
  $('.ui-radio').css('height','100px');
  $('.ui-radio').children().children().css('font-size','18px');
});
$('#rcb').on('click', function(){
    $('.ui-radio').css('height','60px');
    $('.ui-radio').children().children().css('font-size','14px');
});
$('#rcc').on('click', function(){
    $('.ui-radio').css('height','30px');
    $('.ui-radio').children().children().css('font-size','10px');
});
</script>
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQM enhances the radio button by replacing its markup, however, it leaves the original input tag in the dom under the new markup vertically centered within the radio div.  When you set the height to 100px, the enhanced button stays at the top while the input moves to the middle and becomes visible.  Here are 2 options:

Don't resize the button, just change the font size and let the buttons auto-size with the font changes:

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/VVpR9/16/)**

If you need the button size changed to exact height, you can use CSS to hide the input:

```
.ui-radio input{
    display: none;
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/VVpR9/17/)**